# In Go when to write a function with or without a receiver?

Tags: object-oriented, go, static-methods

We're trying to write Go in the most possibile idiomatic way, but sometimes we struggle to find which is the best way.

For example in our service we're creating/converting a struct from another one:

```
type Foo struct {
    ID int
}

type Bar struct {
    ID int
}
```

Is it better to write something like:

```
func convertAtoB(a A) *B {
    return &B{a.ID}
}
```

or something like this?

```
func (a* A) convertToB() *B {
    return &B{a.ID}
}
```

Of course in practice there's no difference, I just would like to understand when to choose one way over the other one.

---

**EDIT:**

I've found an interesting article about this:
https://grisha.org/blog/2016/09/22/golang-receiver-vs-function/

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons to use functions with receivers:

1. You will invoke the method through an interface type.
2. You really like the method-call syntax.

In all other cases (that I'm aware of), normal functions without receiver arguments are preferable.

Comment: +1 for the interface, I didn't thought about that.

Comment: It (making the function a method) helps logically group the function. There's no strict reason why you should do it, other than it's convention. Do note that a method can be called like a function; that is, (T).foo is equivalent to foo(T). It's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled onto a receiver related thing that somehow very quickly someone on the Github found me the answer I was looking for. Just to explain, what I wanted was to be able to embed a first class function that had a receiver - in this case that happened to be exactly the struct type where I wanted to put it. I found a workaround using type Name func syntax, and then creating a private function that was wrapped in a type bound receiver from an interface, but this let me do it differently - the workaround was cumbersome and boilerplatey.

Here is the Github issue:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24996#issuecomment-383424588

I have not been able to find any further documentation about this, but essentially the main points are that you can create an interface{} field in a struct type, and then assign a function bound to an interface method collection, like this:

```
type Name Struct {
  ...
  funcSlot interface{}
  ...
}

func (n *Name) FuncName() error {
  return nil
}

func NewName() (n *Name) {
  ...
  n.funcSlot = (*Name).FuncName
  ...
}

type NAME interface {
  ...
  FuncName() error
  ...
}
```

This passes go vet, at least, I haven't yet confirmed that this has the effect of passing the pointer to the struct so that the function can operate on what is effectively a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this link](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/09/22/golang-receiver-vs-function/). It's one of the best answer I have come across on this subject.

The author concludes,

> Bottom line is that it only makes sense to use a receiver if this function is part of an interface implementation, OR if you never ever need to augment (stub) that function for testing or some other reason. As a practical matter, it seems like (contrary to how it’s done in the OO world) it is better to always start out with quack(d) rather than d.quack().